# Does having multiple PhD offers from top local universities help in US admissions? Should I mention them in my CV?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, cv, india

I have at least 3 offers from some of the top research institutes in my country (Written examination +interviews) in Computer Science.
Should I mention them in my CV? Would it strengthen my CV?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a system where there's a written examination to get into PhD school. Is this written examination public? I.e. could you share your score or percentile?

Comment: Yes, the exams are public. Scores and percentile are mostly kept private but merit list is public. The college Im talking about are IMSc chennai, TIFR mumbai, CMI, ISI kolkata. Each of these college conduct their own test and interviews.

Answer (score 1):

No, on your CV, list only your actual accomplishments and honors, not the offers you never accepted.  List the work you did and the places you studied or worked, not stuff you didn't.

If it does get to the point where you have multiple offers and you're trying to decide between them, that's when those other offers may become relevant.  For example, you might reveal a competing offer as a way of negotiating a better offer from the school you really want.

Comment: Would qualifying a hard test be considered as an accomplishment? I am honestly very proud of being able to qualify those examinations. If yes then, can I list my rank etc as an accomplishment.

Comment: No, I don't think that will help you.  Here in the US, the trend is away from using tests in admissions.  Many graduate admissions committees no longer ask even for GRE scores and they're deliberately ignoring GRE scores if supplied to avoid disadvantaging those who do not supply a GRE score. 
 They're also unlikely even to be familiar with an exam that's not used in the US.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking strategically, I guess I wouldn't mention them. There is a possible upside as you note, but the potential downside is that if people think you are already settled and have other offers there is little need to press for your admittance. And that isn't one of the things that admissions committees are normally looking for in a student. They will do their own analysis of your potential rather than defer to the decisions of others.

But the deeper reason is that if you are good enough to get those offers, then your record is also probably good enough without mentioning them to have a good chance to be accepted at a good US school. But if you make application, don't limit yourself to only top US research institutions. There is too much competition for too few slots for that to be a good strategy. Don't ignore the top places, but also spread out your applications to cover yourself if you really want to study in US.

Comment: Thanks for responding. 
There’s a catch. I have a very bad undergrad GPA. To compensate that I worked very hard and got very good GPA in my masters as well as did a lot of research work. Getting offers from the colleges I mentioned is extremely hard (acceptance around 0.005%). I was thinking adding these offers may validate my CV.

Comment: @Nitish Perhaps you're a better candidate than you think.  If several top colleges have been impressed already, there will likely be more.  Either way, offers you haven't accepted should not go on your CV. It's more likely to strike readers as inappropriate than impressive.

Comment: @Nitish I would certainly entertain your application if you note the following: (i) that your undergrad GPA is poor, and how you worked to improve your background, (ii) that you have offers from top local universities, and why you want to join my university.  At least for me, I look at the whole package.   I've met many students who bloomed later in life.

Comment: @VitaminE Yes, I agree with this.  Other offers don't belong in a CV, but it could go into a personal statement or a statement of purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This system isn't familiar to American admissions committees. Institutions don't have admission exams<sup>1</sup>. There's the [GRE](https://www.ets.org/gre/), but many departments don't see it as very useful, and that's not administered locally. So listing acceptances will make it look like you don't understand US admissions, and I suspect a committee might not want to spend time on a student on the other side of the planet who already has local options.

> The colleges I'm talking about are: IMSc Chennai, TIFR Mumbai, CMI, ISI Kolkata. ([comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/175188/does-having-multiple-phd-offers-from-top-local-universities-help-in-us-admission?noredirect=1#comment470308_175188); edited for grammar)

I haven't heard of any of these universities - although I'm not in Computer Science. So unfortunately, name-dropping these might not be very useful.

Here is how I would list it in an **awards/honors** section:

> Passed national competitive entrance exams at: Institute of Mathematical Sciences, Chennai (percentile: 98th) ...

or maybe

> Passed national competitive entrance exams at: Institute of Mathematical Sciences, Chennai (pass rate: 30%, n = 6,000) ...

You'll have to mess around with the formatting and maybe not list all five depending on spacing, etc.

---

1: Except maybe for some licensed professions.